# Django: click image and have it open in a new page

Tags: django, image, hyperlink

New to django and python so please give me your advice in really simple terms.

Basically I have an image hosting site and I want to be able to click on any image and have it open a new page with the image displayed. How do I do this? I presume I have to get the images url but I am not sure how. This also has to be automatic.

Models:

```
class UploadImages(models.Model):

    category_choice=(('Full','Full Beard'),
                ('tashe', 'Moustache'),
                ('goat','Goatee'))

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='rate', blank=True)
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=128, default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now())
    #category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=category_choice)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views:

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        #images_list = UploadImages.objects.order_by('-date')
        images_list = UploadImages.objects.filter(category='tashe')
        category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
        page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]

        context_dict = {'images':images_list}
        response = render(request,'RateMyBeard/index.html', context_dict)
        return response

    else:
        rating = request.POST['submit']
        #images_list = UploadImages.objects.order_by('-date')
        images_list = UploadImages.objects.filter(category='tashe')
        print rating
        #print images_list

        return render(request, 'RateMyBeard/index.html', images_list)
```

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %} <!-- New line -->



{% block body_block %}

<p> 'check our images'</p>

             {% for image in images %}
                 <a href="upload/">
                 <img src="{{image.image.url}}" alt="{{image.name}}" >
                    </a>

              {% endfor %}

  {% csrf_token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the `target="_blank"` attribute to you `<a>` tag and link will be opened in new window/tab:

```
<a href="{{image.image.url}}" target="_blank">
    <img src="{{image.image.url}}" alt="{{image.name}}">
</a>
```